# How to install maven with brew but without openjdk?

Tags: maven, homebrew

I already have Java HotSpot JDK 11 on my machine that I'm using for everything.

When I typed `brew install maven` it tried to install `openjdk` as a dependency. I don't want that and want maven to use my JDK, not its own `openjdk`.

So, how can I tell it to not install `openjdk`?

Comment: Based on the help there seemed to be an option `--ignore-dependencies` but it's mentioned to be `An unsupported Homebrew development flag to                                     skip installing any dependencies of any...` ?...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After installing java, I have installed Maven with command

```
brew install --ignore-dependencies maven
```

It worked for me, for Gradle also.

Answer (score 10):

The way I solved it was installing the openjdk with brew (in my case openjdk@8). Mine was different from the default one that brew requires by default. So after that I created a symlink to my openjdk where maven is expecting to find the SDK. And finally installed maven without dependencies.

```
brew install openjdk@8
cd /usr/local/opt
ln -s ../Cellar/openjdk@8/1.8.0+275 openjdk
brew install --ignore-dependencies maven
```

Comment: This worked for me.  But I think it may cause problems in the future if you install another package which depends on openjdk.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a supported way to not install a dependency from the command line.  However, you can configure the installed `mvn` to use another JDK.  It requires two steps:

1. Add `/usr/local/opt/maven/libexec/bin` to your `$PATH` before `/usr/local/bin` to pick up the `mvn` script that does not override `$JAVA_HOME`
2. Set `$JAVA_HOME` in your environment or `.mavenrc` to pick up the your preferred version of Java

Answer (score 3):

or (building on what Enrique Cordero said above) to re-use an already installed AdoptOpenJDK 8:

```
brew install adoptopenjdk8
cd /usr/local/opt
ln -s ../Caskroom/adoptopenjdk8/8,275:b01 ./openjdk
brew install maven --ignore-dependencies
```

and then remove the symlink

```
rm /usr/local/opt/openjdk
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer for the asked question, but if someone wants to change the JDK path from the default openjdk to the system defined JDK, one can do the following:

First, `brew install maven` - this will install maven (and openjdk) on the mac and point the default JDK used by maven to be this openjdk

Second, set JAVA_HOME in your ~/.bashrc or  ~/.zshrc to  point to sytem  installed JDK

```
# set JAVA_HOME for mvn
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
```