# Not able to install Maven in Mac OS

Tags: javascript, java, maven

Facing some issue while installing Maven.
I have set the path in my Bash profile. Still "mvn -version" command doesn't work.

Downloaded latest version of maven:
[image]

Added it to my Bash profile:

[image]

**java -version** works. 
But **mvn -version** doesn't.

[image]

What am I missing here???

Comment: How did you install Maven?  From *.tar.gz or *.zip?

Comment: Not that it is your immediate problem, but your JAVA_HOME should end with ".../Home" so the mvn script works properly.

Comment: @Allen  *.tar.gz and I tried JAVA_HOME with ".../Home" in the end, it didn't work.

Comment: I would have guessed ZIP but it is still worth investigating: make sure the mvn script is executable: `chmod a+x $MAVEN_PATH/bin/mvn`

Comment: @Allen u know what screw this. I'm gonna "brew install maven". This is just a waste of time. I'm sorry I wasted your time too man.

Comment: I also just noticed that you're editing your .bash_profile but seem to be running zsh.  I am not sure is Mac OS has compatibility settings for zsh to use bash dot files.  In any event, in bash you need logout/login (or new terminal session) to pick up .bash_profile changes.

Comment: No worries.  Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336020/how-to-install-maven-with-brew-but-without-openjdk/63343062#63343062) for using a specific JDK with Home Brew installed Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MacOS shell has changed from bash to zsh.

`export` will most likely show that your configuration settings wasn't read as zsh uses different configuration files than bash.

Investigate `man zsh` to understand the details.  You will most likely need to move your settings to `~/.zshenv`.  Again use `export` in a fresh shell to see that your settings are active.